# react dropdown using ref and select tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, react-redux

I'm trying to make a drop down with select tag and which triggers when I click on it which is happening right now but I want to make that clickable even when the mouse click happens on its header which is in the same div).

So for example if I click on 'My Text" it should open dropdown... for this I used refs but no luck.

Thanks for your time.

```
focusTextInput() {
        this.textInput.current.onfocus();
      }

render() {
        return (
            <div className='row abc-container'>
                <div className='abc-tag' >
                    <div className="text" onClick={this.focusTextInput}> My Text 
                        <select className="key-list"   ref={this.textInput}
                        value ={this.props.activeClient} >
                            <option >10</option>
                            <option >20</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Comment: focusTextInput() {
        this.textInput.current.onfocus();
      }

render() {
        return (
            <div className='row abc-container'>
                <div className='abc-tag' >
                    <div className="text" onClick={this.focusTextInput}> My Text 
                        <select className="key-list"   ref={this.textInput}
                        value ={this.props.activeClient} >
                            <option >10</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

Comment: Have you tried setting a `state` that determines the visibility of the dropdown itself, and the state value is toggled by the clicks on the `My Text` header?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `state` to control the visibility of dropdown. I usually use CSS to change display of a component. Like this:

```
state = { isShowDropdown: false }

<div 
    className="text" 
    onClick={() => this.setState({ isShowDropdown: !this.state.isShowDropdown })}
> 
    My Text 
    <select
        style={{ display: this.state.isShowDropdown ? "initial" : "none" }}
        className="key-list" ref={this.textInput}
        value ={this.props.activeClient} 
    >
        <option>10</option>
        <option>20</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Hope this help :)